# Order string sequences within a cell

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have the following data in a column of a Pandas dataframe:

`col_1
,B91-10,B7A-00,B7B-00,B0A-01,B0A-00,B64-03,B63-00,B7B-01
,B8A-01,B5H-02,B32-02,B57-00
,B83-01,B83-00,B5H-00
,B83-01,B83-00
,B83-00,B83-01
,B83-00,B92-00,B92-01,B0N-02
,B91-16`

FYI: each of these strings begins with a comma, so the above example has 7 rows.

The order of these different codes in a row do not matter. Rows 3 and 4 (assuming index starts at 0) are identical for my purpose.

I need to order these different codes in each row so that I can get accurate counts of each of them.

In other words, I need to turn it into this:

`col_1
B0A-00,B0A-01,B63-00,B64-03,B7A-00,B7B-00,B7B-01,B91-10
B32-02,B57-00,B5H-02,B8A-01
B5H-00,B83-00,B83-01
B83-00,B83-01
B83-00,B83-01
B0N-02,B83-00,B92-00,B92-01
B91-16`

Not sure where to begin because the strings differ in the number of values. I tried splitting based on the comma but then had no idea how to sort columns when the rows have different numbers of values across the columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't obvious how you want to sort it. Lexicographically?

Comment: You say that you need to sort in the dataframe to get accurate counts of each. What is your *end* goal? Counting tasks don't normally involve sorting, which is why this may be important.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missed detail @COLDSPEED (I thought that my example would be enough.) Yes, I would like to sort it lexicographically, but that's not entirely necessary. The point is to make sure that if two sequences are "a,b" and "b,a", that the both get converted into the same order so that they are identified as the same.

Comment: @jpp: The end goal is to reduce the number of levels of a feature for modeling. As it is, "a,b" and "b,a" are functionally identical for my purpose, so they need to be identified as the same level. However, they are coded as unique levels of a categorical variable in my model. Additionally, there are hundreds of different levels, so I want to reduce them to the unique values constituting the top 90% and then an "Others" level. To do this, I need a frequency distribution, which requires counting.

Comment: `collections.Counter(lst)` will give a you a count of every distinct item in `list`. It's O(n) complexity so should be efficient. Would that not help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
If you want to sort these lexicographically, split on comma and then use `np.sort`:

```
v = np.sort(df.col_1.str.split(',', expand=True).fillna(''), axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(v).agg(','.join, 1).str.strip(',')
```

```
df

0    B0A-00,B0A-01,B63-00,B64-03,B7A-00,B7B-00,B7B-...
1                          B32-02,B57-00,B5H-02,B8A-01
2                                 B5H-00,B83-00,B83-01
3                                        B83-00,B83-01
4                                        B83-00,B83-01
5                          B0N-02,B83-00,B92-00,B92-01
6                                               B91-16
```

---

**Option 2**
Split on comma and call `apply` + `sorted`:

```
df.col_1.str.split(',').apply(sorted, 1).str.join(',').str.strip(',')

0    B0A-00,B0A-01,B63-00,B64-03,B7A-00,B7B-00,B7B-...
1                          B32-02,B57-00,B5H-02,B8A-01
2                                 B5H-00,B83-00,B83-01
3                                        B83-00,B83-01
4                                        B83-00,B83-01
5                          B0N-02,B83-00,B92-00,B92-01
6                                               B91-16
Name: col_1, dtype: object
```

Thanks to @Dark for the improvement!

Comment: Without using lambda maybe : `df.col_1.str.strip(',').str.split(',').apply(sorted).str.join(',')`

Comment: @Dark Awesome, that's certainly better. Thanks :)